# Attach physical menu button to my preferences screen

Tags: android, preferencescreen

My app has a classic PreferenceScreen which activity is triggered by a dedicated button on my UI.

When I click the "Menu" button of the AVD, or the physical menu button on my device, a "Parameter" button shows at the bottom of the screen : pressing on it has no effect, how can I attach it to my actual preference screen, just like my button already does ? Thanks.

(I guess all I need is to be able to find it to attach a OnClick listener to it)

EDIT : I am targeting API Level 14+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it : by tracking key "action_settings" that was automatically generated, I ended up un MyMainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), which is a stub for selected options.

I just had to create and launch an Intent to my Settings activity from here.